# Using a button to reference a radio button option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML.  I'm positive the HTML is error free.

My JavaScript is written in psydocode due to the amount of problems I have with correct syntax.

The 3000 miles needs to be a value that visibly changes every time the button is clicked if the player does not die.

I need to figure out a syntax that links the play button to a radio button option, Checks to see if the user randomly died - if not - subtracts 500 miles from the total miles that needs to be traveled (3000), then check to see if the mile counter is 0.

Thank you for your time!

```
    <body>
    <h1>Coal Train the Game!<h1>
    <h3> Pick one track. Be careful to read the track descriptions,
    some tracks have a better chance to reach Oregon than others!  
    After strategically choosing a track, click the button to travel 500 miles.
    At the end of 3000 miles, you win the game!<h3>


    <img src="coaltrain.jpg" alt="Picture of Train" style="width:600px;height:300">


    <table>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="You Changed Tracks!" id="Track_1" value="1" onclick="alert(this.name);" /></td>
    <td valign="top" style="color: red;">Scenic Bridge Track - Choose this track if you enjoy old bridges!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="You Changed Tracks!" id="Track_2" value="2" checked="checked" onclick="alert(this.name);" /></td>
    <td valign="top" style="color: blue;">Outlaw Town Track - Choose this track if you enjoy talking to unrefined characters!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="You Changed Tracks!" id="Track_3" value="3" onclick="alert(this.name);" /></td>
    <td valign="top" style="color: green;">Active Volcano Track - Choose this track if you enjoy liquid hot magma!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="You Changed Tracks!" id="Track_4" value="4" onclick="alert(this.name);" /></td>
    <td valign="top" style="color: orange;">Boring Track - Choose this track if you prefer safety over experience</td>
</tr>
</table>


<div id="Miles" value = "3000"> 3000 Miles to Travel!</div>

<button id="Play" onclick="myFunction()">Play</button>

</html> 

function myFunction = If Track_1 = "checked" 

then

Math.Random()<=.25 then alert(The Coal Train died by falling through a bridge!) 

else
    var Miles 
    var OneTurn
    var Total = "Miles"-"One Turn"

if var Miles = 0 

then alert(Your Coal Train made it too Oregon!  Congrats!);
```

Comment: Your html has mismatched `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Could you please fix it and indent it better ?

Comment: Moreover, there is no real question here. Are you expecting us to write the code for you ? I don't get it.

Comment: share what you have tried(myFunction) - try to create a demo by editing http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r4qbkm2L/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction = If Track_1 = "checked" 

then

Math.Random()<=.25 then alert(The Coal Train died by falling through a bridge!) 

else
    var Miles 
    var OneTurn
    var Total = "Miles"-"One Turn"

if var Miles = 0 

then alert(Your Coal Train made it too Oregon!  Congrats!);
```

---

> Below is the syntax for your Js code

```
function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById('Track_1').checked) {
        if(Math.random()<=.25) {
          alert("The Coal Train died by falling through a bridge!");
        }
        else {
          var Miles;
          var OneTurn;
          var Total = Miles-OneTurn;
          if(Miles==0) {
            alert("Your Coal Train made it too Oregon! Congrats!);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

> The way you are calling a function is right. So, when the button gets clicked, the code checks for the '**#Track_1**" input (radio box)...
>
> Though I had written the code; I had built up the if-else ladder hierarchy based on "indentation" provided in your ***psydocode***